# Mutiple functions and ggplots using a for loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop, ggplot2, nested-loops

I want to generate a number of plots of linear regressions (bacterial OTUs plotted against temperature) using ggplot. I want the titles of the plots to be the linear regression equation, which I am determining with a function. The code works when I make the plots individually but not when I use a for loop.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = taxa_list[i] ~ Temperature, data = dataframe,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Temperature')
```

See below for my code. Do I need a nested for loop to make this work?

```
taxa_list <- c("Vibrio","Salmonella","Campylobacter","Listeria","Streptococcus","Legionella")
taxa_list <- sort(taxa_list)

for (i in seq_along(taxa_list)) {

  lm_eqn <- function(dataframe) {
    m <- lm(taxa_list[i] ~ Temperature, dataframe)
    p <- summary(m)
    eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2 %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(p)~"="~p0, 
                     list(a = format(unname(coef(m)[1]), digits = 2),
                          b = format(unname(coef(m)[2]), digits = 2),
                          r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3), 
                          p0 = format(p$coefficients[8], digits = 3)))
    as.expression(eq);
  }

    plot <- ggplot(data = all_data, aes(x = Temperature, y = taxa_list[i], fill = taxa_list[i])) + 
            geom_point(data = all_data, aes(x = Temperature, y = taxa_list[i]), color = "black", size = 3) +
            geom_smooth(method = "lm", size = 1, color = "black", fill = "gray") +
            labs(title = lm_eqn(dataframe = all_data), subtitle = "") + xlab("Temperature") + ylab("Number of OTUs")

    print(plot)

}
```

Comment: Replace the formula `taxa_list[i] ~ Temperature` with `as.formula(paste0(taxa_list[i], " ~ Temperature"))`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to rewrite your code to make it more readable, efficient and maintainable.  I used `tidyverse` choices.  I believe there was an extra `* x` in your original `eq` function that I removed.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(broom)


taxa_list <- c("Vibrio","Salmonella","Campylobacter","Listeria","Streptococcus","Legionella")
taxa_list <- sort(taxa_list)

MyFunctionNew <- function(data, bacteria, temperature) 
{  
  my_lm <- lm(as.formula(paste(bacteria, "~", temperature)), data = data)
  terms_info <- broom::tidy(my_lm)
  model_info <- broom::glance(my_lm)
  eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2 *","~~italic(p)~"="~p0, 
                   list(a = format(terms_info$estimate[1], digits = 2),
                        b = format(terms_info$estimate[2], digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(model_info$r.squared, digits = 3), 
                        p0 = format(model_info$p.value, digits = 3)))


  plot <- ggplot(data = data, aes_string(x = temperature, y = bacteria, fill = bacteria)) + 
    geom_point(size = 3, show.legend = TRUE) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", size = 1, color = "black", fill = "gray") +
    labs(title = eq, subtitle = "") + xlab("Temperature") + ylab("Number of OTUs")

  return(plot)
}

MyFunctionNew(dat1, "Vibrio", "Temperature")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
purrr::map(taxa_list, ~ MyFunctionNew(dat1, .x, "Temperature"))
#> [[1]]
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's some made up data that should more or less be close enough

```r
set.seed(1111)
dat1 <- data.frame(Temperature = runif(200, min = 32, max = 100),
                   Vibrio = rnorm(200),
                   Salmonella = rnorm(200),
                   Campylobacter = rnorm(200),
                   Listeria = rnorm(200),
                   Streptococcus = rnorm(200),
                   Legionella = rnorm(200) 
                   )
```

Comment: Yes I picked that up from his initial attempt.  Couldn't figure out even whether a legend is wanted, it it were me I'd put it up in the title somewhere.